# Groovy get variables from file. variable=value

Tags: groovy, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Seems like this question for most of others looks too simple.
I need a help with following problem.
Has file(p.envs) with set of variables and values like:

```
VARIABLE=foo
NOW=19 October 2014
```

How to read this file with Groovy to get an output like:

```
    new File('p.envs').eachLine { line ->
       println line
       ...
    }
    ...
    println "NOW=$NOW"
    println "$NOW"
```

Output:

```
NOW=19 October 2014
19 October 2014
```

This issue can help someone to inject custom variables to groovy template in Editable Email Notification Plugin in Jenkins.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are working with a file that follows the Java properties format you can use [ConfigSlurper](http://groovy.codehaus.org/ConfigSlurper) to parse it:

```
def config = new ConfigSlurper().parse(new File('p.envs').toURL())
```

The [config object](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/util/ConfigObject.html) implements Map so you can print the values like this:

```
config.each { key, value -> println "$key=$value" }
```

Comment: Thanks! But I got an exception: Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.Integer.call() is applicable for argument types: (groovy.util.ConfigObject) values: [[:]]
Possible solutions: wait(), abs(), any(), wait(long), any(groovy.lang.Closure), each(groovy.lang.Closure)
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.Integer.call() is applicable for argument types: (groovy.util.ConfigObject) values: [[:]]

Comment: Sorry, guys. Solution found. Property file should be in VAR="$VALUE" format. I just forgot double quotes. Thanks a lot once again.